# Как сравнить 2 csv файла Python?

Tags: python, csv

Есть 2 csv файла  с одним столбцом 'name'. Надо записать в первый csv файл, отсутсвующие в первом файле  строки из второго файла.
Например.Во втором файле есть строка Ivan. В первом файле его нет. Нужно строку Ivan записать в конец первого файла. Если строка Masha есть в первом файле то из второго файла строка Masha не записывается.

Comment: Что вы сделали для решения данной задачи и на чем застопорились?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос примеры файлов и желаемый результат. И код попытки решения тоже.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = ['de', 'tr', 'tt', 'rr']
d2 = ['df', 'ff', 'tt']
d3 = []
for i in range(len(d2)):
    if d2[i] not in d1:
        d3.append(d2[i])
    else:
        continue


for f in d3:
    d1.append(f)


print(d1)
```

Comment: Хорошо, но в решении нет csv файлов.